# Tkinter: как создать дочернее окно и скрыть родительское?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть главное окно и него нужно вызвать родительское, при этом главное скрыть. Потом через какое-то время закрыть дочернее и показать родительское.

Сейчас создаю так

Конструктор класса

```
    self.root = Tk()
    self.main = MainWindow(self.root)
    self.main.StartServerEvent+=self.OnServerStart

    self.root.mainloop()
```

Затем когда срабатывает ивент

```
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root.quit()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.gameWindow = Game(self.root, self.server)
    self.root.mainloop()
```

До этого момента работает, но как теперь вот восстановить первое окно?

Comment: Это которое Вы уничтожили (destroy)?

Comment: Да, которое я уничтожил как восстановить?
Я просто не знал как его скрыть, вот и уничтожал, а потом планировал просто пересоздать.

Comment: А может не надо его уничтожать? Спрятать?

       self.root.withdraw()
       ...
       self.root.deiconify()

Comment: да, пожалуй, так можно. но не утечка ли памяти это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы скрыть окно нужно использовать метод `withdraw` он скрывает окно не уничтожая его.

```
self.root.withdraw()
```

Что бы потом сделать скрытое окно видимым используй метод `deiconify`.

```
self.root.deiconify()
```

Подробнее об этих методах можно почитать [здесь](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm).